# Trimming string before substring in VB .Net

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to find a way to trim strings before a substring, in a way that only the left of the string is returned.

Before:

```
[REMOVE] = 1 (Line0)
G77 H9002 (Line1)
[ZAXIS] = 25 (Line2)
```

After:

```
[REMOVE] = 1
G77 H9002 
[ZAXIS] = 25
```

I want to trim the strings before the "(line" substring (removing all characters remaining on the right as well).
In VBA this was easily achievable but in VB .Net its not so straightforward.
Could you please direct me to a possible solution?
Thanks

Comment: As concernd to your missing source code: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes, (Line0), (Line1),..., (Linen) are part of the strings. The lines are separated by the New Line Character (vbCrLf). Maybe that is something I can explore...

Comment: Does the part you want to trim off *always* start with a `(` and is there ever a `(` that would not be trimmed off? Generally, whatever you did in VBA can be done with little-to-no modification in VB.NET, so if you had shown us the code we could have made suggestions based on that.

Comment: Hi Andrew. I do not have any VBA code to show at this moment. However I remember how I did it. First I extracted the length of the string (with the function Length) and then used the function Left. That is what I will try to replicate in Vb. Net when I get my hands on the actual code again. Thank for all of your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim strs = File.ReadLines("c:\\SomeFile.txt") 'Read the file

Using sw = File.CreateText("c:\Target")  'File to save to
    For Each str In strs
        Dim i = str.LastIndexOf("(Line") 'Find the index to cut
        Dim newStr = str.Substring(0, i) 'Cut the line at index
        sw.WriteLine(newStr)             'Write new string to new file.
    Next
End Using
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried something similar, except I do not want to declare the strings in advance. They will be opened from a file and anything can be there. The only known part is the "(Line...)"

Comment: @BrunoLopes Ok, so it is one string with mutiple lines?

Comment: In that case just replace the first line with a call to read the lines from the specified file. You might also want to read only the last index of `(Line` in case there are more entries on the line. (Use `LastIndexOf`)